# How to get same outputs with JavaScript and swig?

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-in-loop, swig-template

```
var json = {
"color" : {
    "off-white" : {
        "inactive" : 0,
        "instock" : 5,
        "prestock" : 49
    },
    "red" : {
        "prestock" : 50,
        "instock" : 10,
        "inactive" : 0
    }
  }
};
```

In JavaScript if I do

```
  for (var col in json.color) {
      result += col  + " = " + JSON.stringify(json.color[col].prestock)+ "\n";
  }
```

I can get "off-white" and "red" and all the sub-documents.

I did the same thing but it won't give me the same outputs.
What else can I do?

To get the outputs of "off-white" and "red" I have to

```
{% for col in Object.keys(json.color) %}
```

But I can't access to sub-documents.

If I do

```
{% for col in json.color %}
<li>{{Object.keys(col)}}</li>
```

I get

```html
<li>"off-white", "red"</li>
```

I need them separately, like:

```html
<li>off-white</li>
<li>red</li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In swig, you can get both the key and the value without using `Object.keys`:

```
{% for key, val in json.color %}
  <li>{{ key }} = {{ val.prestock }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

That should give you the same thing you're asking for in the JavaScript example.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript you should do like

```
json.color.off-white  OR json['color']['off-white']
```

// it will give you an object like

```
{
   "inactive" : 0,
   "instock" : 5,
   "prestock" : 49
}

// check  alert(JSON.stringify(json.color.off-white));
```

This  won't return an Array so you won't be able to loop through it.

further you can get value of `inactive` by accessing object like  `json.color.off-white.inactive`

Comment: Thanks but as you can see i can do it with Javascript, i need to have same output with swig.

Answer (score 0):

So to separately display them I think you need do something like this:

```
{% for key in Object.keys(json.color) %}
  <li>{{ key }},{{json["color"][key]["prestock"]}}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Sorry, I suppose you already have the color keys. Now I update the code, hope works.

Comment: but this doesn't return "off-white" or "red" but access to "prestock", "instock", and "inactive"